# How do I pass input to click.confirm without running CLIrunner.invoke()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-click

I have a use case where a function seeks user confirmation to proceed. This is basically:

```
def abc()
    response = click.confirm("Do you want to continue?")
```

Based on this response, it either aborts or proceeds.

The problem is to test this function `abc`.

```
@click.option('--yes', prompt=True)
def test_abc():
    with mock.patch.object(click.confirm, input="n"):
        click.echo("Aborted")
```

Comment: What does the rest of your module that contains `abc` look like? Usually you'd patch a function like `patch('<module>.click.confirm', return_value=True)`.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but I had the same issue, I decided to mock the `click.confirm` which allowed me to simulate someone selecting `[y/N]`

lets say your `abc()` looked like this:

```
def abc():
    if click.confirm("do you want to continue?", abort=True):
        return "Confirmed"

    return "Aborted"
```

and then your tests mock the `click.confirm` to `y/n`

```
@mock.patch("click.confirm")
def test_abc_aborted(mock_click):
    mock_click.return_value = False
    assert abc() == "Aborted"


@mock.patch("click.confirm")
def test_abc_confirmed(mock_click):
    mock_click.return_value = "y"
    assert abc() == "Confirmed"
```